# ajax not posting to php onclick

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
           $(function(){
                $(".product-item").click(function(){
                    var sku = $(this).attr("name");
                    var dataString = "sku="+sku;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "data.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(){
                            $("#product").load("shop4.php #product > *", function(){
                                $("#product").delay(200).fadeOut(400);
                                $("#product").delay(601).fadeIn();
                                $(".img-wrap img").delay(500).fadeIn(300);
                                $(".img-wrap img").delay(300).animate({paddingBottom: "15%"});
                                $(".img-wrap img").hover(function(){
                                    $(this).animate({
                                        paddingTop: "5%", paddingBottom: "25%"
                                    });
                                }, function(){
                                    $(this).animate({
                                        paddingTop: "15%", paddingBottom: "15%"
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

After I click product-item the product section fades out and then fades in with all the correct information however the php is not reading the post data, something of note is that to get the click function to work I had to place this script after div id product.

php is simple (this is data.php):

```
<?php
global $sku;
if (isset($_POST['sku'])) {
    $sku = $_POST['sku'];
    echo $sku;
}
?>
```

XHR response

```
XHR finished loading: "mysite.com/shop4.php". jquery.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) shop4.php:238
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i jquery.min.js:3
XHR finished loading: "mysite.com/shop4.php". jquery.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.load jquery.min.js:4
$.ajax.success shop4.php:243
f.Callbacks.o jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
w jquery.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that you have the dataType set to "html" but you seem to be simply returning text.

Comment: What does shop4.php look like? Has it an element with id product, and what's `> *` good for?

Comment: @Jørgen the `>*` is to make sure it does not load the div product inside the div product but instead just loads it once.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few strange things in your code.

1) You don't use the response from the AJAX call anywhere.  `success` takes an argument that supplies the response from the call, but you never use it.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(resp) {
        // do something with resp object
    }
});
```

2) You have a `return false;` statement in your function, which will execute immediately after the AJAX call is made (it won't wait).  So your function will always return false immediately, not sure if that's the behavior you're looking for.

Aside from those two items, can you use an XHR debugger like Chrome's built-in or Firebug and see what's actually being sent/received from the server?